# Accidentally stopped command in middle of git checkout how do I recover

Tags: git

I ran git checkout  and stopped the process in the middle.  Now I can't switch branches because it complains I'll overwrite local files.  How do I get around this? eg

git checkout egotailer 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:


...

I tried

git clean -d -x -f

but it didn't help

Comment: Checkout the HEAD of the current branch, and then switch?

Comment: you can combine single letter options on git commands. `git clean -xdf`

Answer (score 4):

well, if you know that your repository is all up to date and that you have nothing outstanding to be checked in, simply reset your branch back to the HEAD.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --hard
```

should do it. `HEAD` is implied when you don't specify a reference.

**WARNING This is the most common way to lose work in Git!!**

A safer way to clean your directory is

```
git stash -u
```

or

```
git stash --include-untracked
```

This will do what `git reset --hard` does but you can't accidentally lose information. It is only available as of version 1.7.7. Before that you had to

```
git add -A && git stash
```

for the same effect.

Later, if you realize you are missing important work, you can get it back from the stash.